Next middleware i18n
I have a problem with middleware in nextjs app. It performs page rewriting if the user enters the defauld locale and it works for users but not for google. It gives a 500 error and does not allow advertising to be launched along this path.

import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'

import { i18n } from './i18n-config'

import { match as matchLocale } from '@formatjs/intl-localematcher'
import Negotiator from 'negotiator'

function getLocale(request: NextRequest): string | undefined {
  const negotiatorHeaders: Record<string, string> = {}
  request.headers.forEach((value, key) => (negotiatorHeaders[key] = value))

  // @ts-ignore locales are readonly
  const locales: string[] = i18n.locales
  const languages = new Negotiator({ headers: negotiatorHeaders }).languages()
 
  const locale = matchLocale(languages, locales, i18n.defaultLocale)
  return locale
}

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const pathname = request.nextUrl.pathname
  const searchParams = request.nextUrl.searchParams

  const currentUser = request.cookies.get('token')?.value

  if (request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/lists')) {
    return Response.redirect(new URL('/catalog/lists ', request.url))
  }

  if (request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/kz/lists')) {
    return Response.redirect(new URL('/kz/catalog/lists ', request.url))
  }

  if (!currentUser && request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/cabinet')) {
    return Response.redirect(new URL('/login', request.url))
  }

  if (!currentUser && request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/kz/cabinet')) {
    return Response.redirect(new URL('/kz/login', request.url))
  }

  if (!currentUser && request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/basket')) {
    return Response.redirect(new URL('/login', request.url))
  }

  if (!currentUser && request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/kz/basket')) {
    return Response.redirect(new URL('/kz/login', request.url))
  }

  const pathnameIsMissingLocale = i18n.locales.every(
    locale => !pathname.startsWith(`/${locale}/`) && pathname !== `/${locale}`
  )

  // Redirect if there is no locale
  if (pathnameIsMissingLocale) {
    const locale = getLocale(request)

    if (locale === i18n.defaultLocale) {
      // Redirect if there is no locale
      if (pathnameIsMissingLocale) {
        return NextResponse.rewrite(
          new URL(
            `/${locale}${pathname.startsWith('/') ? '' : '/'}${pathname}${searchParams.toString() ? `?${searchParams.toString()}` : ''}`,
            request.url
          )
        )
      }
    }

    return NextResponse.redirect(
      new URL(
        `/${locale}${pathname.startsWith('/') ? '' : '/'}${pathname}${searchParams.toString() ? `?${searchParams.toString()}` : ''}`,
        request.url
      )
    )
  }
}

export const config = {
  // Matcher ignoring `/_next/` and `/api/`
  matcher: ['/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)']
}


as a result, along the paths for example /en, /kz everything checks out fine, but on the path / which rewrites the page under /en Google gives an error that can be seen on https://pagespeed.web.dev/
maybe someone has encountered this
I tried to do a redirect from /en to /, it also worked for the user, but in Google it didn't change anything, only at the address /en it started to give a 500 error
